# Lambda notation function signature does not compile in ghc, but OK in interpreter (ghci)

Tags: haskell

Lambda notation function signature does not compile in ghc, but OK in interpreter (ghci)
I am using stack on mac osx. ghc version is 8.8.3

```
\x y -> 2*x + y :: Num a => a -> a -> a 
valNum1 = \x y -> 2*x + y
```

Comment: How do you use it in a program that you compile? A lambda expression at the top level does not make much senses.

Comment: I believe that same statement can be made about `1 + 2 :: Int` working in GHCI, but not compiling if placed at the top level of a source file.

Comment: If you put in code something like varInt1 = 1 + 2 :: Int, it compiles fine, here we have a pure signature.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us _exactly_ what you entering into ghci and your source file? Are you aware that the first line of your code parses as `\x y -> 2*x + (y :: Num a => a -> a -> a )`, and that the second line has invalid syntax?

Comment: The item you define is `valNum1`, so the signature should be `valNum1 :: Num a => ...`. Furthermore you should use `valNum1 = \x ...`, and not `valNum1 = = \x ...`.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Willem Van Onsem explained where my problem was in details. An  invalid syntaxes was just a mistyping. Sorry. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you define a signature for the lambda expression, but this lambda expression is an *expression*, not a declaration. If you want to specify the signature, then you specify this as the signature of `valNum1`:

```
valNum1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
valNum1 = \x y -> 2*x + y
```

It is however more convenient to specify the variables in the head of `valNum1`:

```
valNum1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
valNum1 x y = 2*x + y
```

or you can write this as a point-free variant:

```
valNum1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
valNum1 = (+) . (2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks Willem. You explained me a little bit more about Lambda expression. It was an interesting to see different versions of valNum1. Thanks.